# Getting error: "Variable $SETTING is undefined."

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

How can I increase the request timeout from an API written in ColdFusion? I have written this service in ColdFusion and need to increase the request timeout for this service.

```
public struct function get(string CI="", string startDate="", string endDate="")
{
    loc.requestTimeout=6000;
    setting(requestTimeout=loc.requestTimeout);  
}
```

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you running? You have tagged both versions 9 and 10. The `cfscript` version of `cfsetting` was not introduced until version 10.

Comment: HI I am using CF11

Comment: Hi Miguel, Please response at earliest. It's very imp for me

Comment: Here it is taking 6000 means 6000 sec. Am I right?

Comment: The google search string that tells you what the number 6000 represents is, `coldfusion requesttimeout1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax instead:

```
setting requesttimeout=30;
```

Or using your variable:

```
setting requesttimeout=loc.requestTimeout;
```

*Notice that there are no parenthesis*

The `requesttimeout` setting takes an integer value which sets the number of seconds.

> Time limit, after which ColdFusion processes the page as an unresponsive thread. Overrides the time-out set in the ColdFusion Administrator.

Comment: Hi Miguel.. Worked fine. Thank a lot